# How to sort $(xml).children()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

**How can i sort xml elements by tagName (nodeName) when i call $(xml).children()?**

I was hoping i can do something like **$(xml).children().sort()** but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example: (http://jsfiddle.net/bdMn3/1/)

Code:

```
var xml = "<data><itemB>more data</itemB><itemC>yes, more data</itemC><itemA>some data</itemA></data>";

var info = $("#info");

$(xml).children().each(function () {
    var xmlnode = $(this);
    info.append(this.tagName + " - " + xmlnode.text() + "<br/>");
});
```

Current Results:

```
ITEMB - more data
ITEMC - yes, more data
ITEMA - some data
```

**Desired Results:**

```
ITEMA - some data
ITEMB - more data
ITEMC - yes, more data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort` function takes a compare function as a parameter.

```
$(xml).children().sort(function(a, b) { return a.tagName > b.tagName ? 1 : a.tagName < b.tagName ? -1 : 0; })
```

Comment: You really should account for the keys being equal, because that could screw up the sort function behavior.

Comment: @Pointy: You mean if i have two equal tagNames?

Comment: Yes - when they're equal, the comparison function should return 0. If it doesn't, then the sort function could get confused when it gets conflicting results comparing two array values in two different orderings (in other words, compare(a, b) then compare(b, a) ...)